# Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'pybind11/pybind11.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, pybind11

I'd like to run T-spline from Github, but this error occurs every time I'm trying to build the project. 
-I put  code and everything else in C:\Program Files (x86). 
-I use pybind/pybind11, -laumaya/GLC_lib . -I use Github extension in MSVC and I download everything directly through the extension .
I run CMake (3.13.1)  for T-spline and looks like everything is fine. I use MSVC 15 2017

Thank you

Comment: That's not enough information to help you. Where is that file located on your machine?

Comment: I tried some different locations , but this last one is C:\Program Files (x86). So the source file and everything else is located there. I thought i had to bring it all together in the same File.

Comment: I thought that i followed the instructrions . Take a look:- Run CMake;
- Specify the source code and binary directories (fill the corresponding entries with value 
  "../SOURCE_DIRECTORY" or drag the "CMakeLists.txt" file);
- Press Configure button, set up the Generator settings(choose the Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) version);
...... 
- Press Generate button(it will generate all the binary files in the SOURCE_DIRECTORY);
- Open tspline.sln file in MSVC and build the solution;

Comment: As soon as i get to the last one" Open tspline.sln..." everything seems to be fine !?      But when i 'm trying to buid it on MSVC , then i always take the same error!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pybind11, then [you shouldn't do it this way](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html).

First make pybind11 a submodule in your git repo, or just check it out in your source tree and call:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdParty/pybind11)
```

Then you can create a pybind module:

```
 pybind11_add_module(${NAME} MODULE ${SRC} ${HEADERS})
```

This way, if something is missing, you will see it when CMake starts, and not during building.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?add_subdirectory(${TSPLINE}/3rdParty/pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(${TSLPINE} MODULE ${TSPLINE} ${TSPLINE})

Comment: Almost. the first argument to add_module is the name you want and then you have the list of the files you want to compile. I don't think ${TSPLINE} is an a name, a folder and a list of files. But you are almost there. See also the documentation for another example of usage (the link in my answer).